# Swift - How to get Raw Value from ENUM

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I have the following enum:

```
enum MembershipLevel: Int {
    
    case basic = 25
    case bronze = 50
    case silver = 100
    case gold = 500
    case platinum = 1000
    
}
```

which then I have the following firebase lookup:

```
userRef.child(userId).child("memeberlevel").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    self.userRef.child(userId).child("count").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in
                
        if((snap.value!) < MembershipLevel.(snapshot.value!).rawValue) {
                    
            completion(false)
                    
        } else {

            completion(true)

        }
                
    })

})
```

The code above throws a complier error due to the following code:

```
MembershipLevel.(snapshot.value).rawValue
```

How can I reference the enum values dynamically, since the code snippet `MembershipLevel.basic.rawValue` is perfectly OK?

Comment: I'm guessing `snapshot.value` is one of "basic", "bronze", "silver" etc?

Comment: Yes, it would be limited to one of those values in the Firebase child node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use an enum here. Enum cases cannot be referred to dynamically.

While you *could* do something like this:

```
enum MembershipLevel: Int, CaseIterable {
    
    case basic = 25
    case bronze = 50
    case silver = 100
    case gold = 500
    case platinum = 1000
    
    init?(string: String) {
        if let value = MembershipLevel.allCases.first(where: { "\($0)" == string }) {
            self = value
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

// usage:
let userValue = snapValue.value as! Int
let membershipString = snapshot.value as! String
if userValue < MembershipLevel(string: membershipString)!.rawValue {
    
}
```

It might break in the future as I don't think `"\($0)"` producing the enum case name is guaranteed.

I would use a dictionary:

```
let membershipLevelNameDict = [
    "basic": 25,
    "bronze": 50,
    "silver": 100,
    "gold": 500,
    "platinum": 1000
]
```

Usage:

```
let userValue = snapValue.value as! Int
let membershipString = snapshot.value as! String
if userValue < membershipLevelNameDict[membershipString] ?? 0 {

}
```

Using this dictionary, you can also create an instance of your enum:

```
membershipLevelNameDict[membershipString].flatMap(MembershipLevel.init(rawValue:))
```

But if you want to compare the raw values, just access the dictionary directly like in the first snippet.

Comment: Why not a simple switch initializer? `extension MembershipLevel {`
    `init?(_ string: String) {`
        `switch string {`
        `case "basic": self = .basic`
        `case "bronze": self = .bronze`
        `case "silver": self = .silver`
        `case "gold": self = .gold`
        `case "platinum": self = .platinum`
        `default: return nil`
        `}`
    `}`
`}`

Comment: The line of code `if snap.value! < membershipLevelNameDict[snapshot.value!] ?? 0 {}` throws the following error `Cannot convert value of type 'Any' to expected argument type 'String'`. If I add the following: `if (snap.value! < MembershipLevel[snapshot.value! as! String]  ?? 0)` then it throws the following error Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any' and 'Int'

Comment: @LeoDabus i was thinking of using the switch statement but wanted to know if there was a better more dynamic way of solving the issue.

Comment: @Learn2Code You need to cast from `Any` to `Int` if value is an integer and from `Any` to `String` if it is a `String`

Comment: @LeoDabus I just find the syntax of dictionaries more lightweight. I mostly use switches for pattern matches or when I want to run statements. Dictionaries are IMO the best at representing this kind of one-to-one correspondence of _values_.

Comment: I don't see any advantage not using a switch in this case

Comment: @Sweeper Even if you use a dictionary it would be better to return the enumeration case instead of its rawValue `let levels: [String: MembershipLevel] = [`
    `"basic": .basic,`
    `"bronze": .bronze,`
    `"silver": .silver,`
    `"gold": .gold,`
    `"platinum": .platinum`
`]` then `levels["basic"]?.rawValue`

Comment: @LeoDabus why? Since we are comparing ints, why make an enum that you throw away immediately?

Comment: You can also initialize both of them and make them conform to comparable. Another option is to create an initializer to take `Any`

Comment: @Learn2Code I've assumed the left hand side is an int and the right hand side is a string. See the edit.

Comment: @Learn2Code what type is `snap`?

Comment: @LeoDabus [`DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot), most likely.

Comment: Nvm I needed to cast `(snap.value! as! Int)` as well so that the < operator would work. Its all good now. Thx to both of you!!

Comment: @Sweeper I meant its value

Answer (score 1):

You can make your enumeration conform to Comparable protocol and create an initializer that takes an Int:

```
extension MembershipLevel: Comparable {
    init?(_ value: Any?) {
        switch value {
        case let int as Int:
            self.init(rawValue: int)
        case let string as String:
            switch string {
                case "basic": self = .basic
                case "bronze": self = .bronze
                case "silver": self = .silver
                case "gold": self = .gold
                case "platinum": self = .platinum
                default: return nil
            }
        default: return nil
        }
    }
    static func < (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        lhs.rawValue < rhs.rawValue
    }
}
```

Now you can initialize your enumeration from the snapshot values and compare them directly

```
if let lhs = MembershipLevel(snap.value),
    let rhs = MembershipLevel(snapshot.value),
    lhs < rhs {      
        completion(false)             
    }
} else { 
    completion(true)
}
```

Comment: thank you for this, it seems to fit as well as a solution. I'll see which one I move forward with. But I do want to thank you both for your prompt responses!!